# Limit cumsum to only the previous 4 rows

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

beginner's question:

I want to create a cumulative sum column on my dataframe, but I only want the column to add the values from the previous 4 rows (inclusive of the current row). I also need to start the count again with each new 'Type' in the frame.

This is what I'm going for:

```
Type    Value    Desired column
  A       1        -
  A       2        -
  A       1        -
  A       1        5
  A       2        6
  A       2        6
  B       2        -
  B       2        -
  B       2        -
  B       2        8
  B       1        7
  B       1        6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by `apply`ing a `rolling_sum` after we `groupby` the Type.  For example:

```
>>> df["sum4"] = df.groupby("Type")["Value"].apply(lambda x: pd.rolling_sum(x,4))
>>> df
   Type  Value  sum4
0     A      1   NaN
1     A      2   NaN
2     A      1   NaN
3     A      1     5
4     A      2     6
5     A      2     6
6     B      2   NaN
7     B      2   NaN
8     B      2   NaN
9     B      2     8
10    B      1     7
11    B      1     6
```

pandas uses `NaN` to represent missing data; if you really want `-` instead, you could do that too, using

```
df["sum4"] = df["sum4"].fillna('-')
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed to solve the problem. Really appreciate it.